# Mormon understanding of what kind of bodies people have in heaven

Tags: lds, heaven, afterlife

This question is about the [article about Heavenly Father at lds.org](https://www.lds.org/topics/god-the-father?lang=eng) which says about God that:

> He “has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man’s” (D&C 130:22).

Some questions I would like to ask about this:

1. Does this mean that Mormons expect to have bodies of flesh and bones
   in heaven?
2. Or, assuming that God is in the third heaven, is it only those who
   gain access to 3rd heaven who end up with bodies of flesh and bones?
3. Will anyone end up in heaven as a spirit person?
4. Is the physical body the reason for the expectation to be able to
   procreate in heaven?

Comment: Sharing my research. Two types of resurrections, the Jesus of Nazareth kind and the Lazarus kind. Physical would just mean that once Jesus was resurrected and given a body that was made out of glory and god stuff, he still had a hole in his palm. He could eat and he could touch people. This is similar to the angels in Soddom, who ate with Lott and could grab him with their hands. Spirits like angels, can take on physical form essentially, but they are not flesh as know it. The spirit body of a divine level entity is not flesh, but acts much like it on our dimension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LDS scriptures can be found [here](https://www.lds.org/scriptures?lang=eng&cid=rdscriptures).

Members of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints (which I am) believe the following:

1) Yes, we believe that "resurrection" means the reuniting of the spirit with flesh.  "The spirit and the body shall be reunited again in its perfect form; both limb and joint shall be restored to its proper frame, even as we now are at this time; and we shall be brought to stand before God..." (Alma 11:43).

2) We believe that all people who were allowed to obtain mortal bodies on this earth will be resurrected.  "We believe man will be punished for his own sins and not for Adam's transgression" (Article of Faith 12).  See also D&C 88:94-101.  It is worth noting we define a difference between "salvation" (the salvation of the physical body due to Adam's fall, i.e., resurrection) and "exaltation" (the glorification of the individual).  Therefore, in LDS theology, everyone is "saved" but only those who truely have faith in Jesus Christ, obey His commandments, and endure to the end, will be "exalted" to the Celestial Kingdom (a discussion of the Kingdoms is a bit beyond the scope of this answer).

3) Yes and no.  Three perspectives exist in the LDS world as to "heaven" and "hell".  (a) The time between death and resurrection/judgement.  This is time spend in what we colloquially call "the spirit world".  There is a "Spirit Paradise" and a "Spirit Prison".  (Alma 40:11-14)  These can be considered, respectively, heaven and hell.  (b) After judgement, people are sent to (basically) one of four places: The Celestial Kingdom (highest glory), the Terrestrial Kingdom, the Telestial Kingdom, and Outer Darkness (also called "Perdition", a place with no glory).  The line between Outer Darkness and the three other kingdoms can be defined as heaven and hell.  This is specifically supported by the teachings of the Second Death or loss of our Second Estate (Rev 2:11; 20:6,14; Alma 12:16,32; D&C 76:30-49) which separates those in outer darkness from everyone else.  Then there is (c), which is an unfortunate form of elitism in the Church, where people draw the line beneath the Celestial Kingdom.  That's heaven, everywhere else is hell.  It has one scriptual justification, the Celestial Kingdom is where our Heavenly Father dwells, and no where else (D&C 76:62,77).  So, Spirit World, everyone is a Spirit.  After judgement, no spirits.

4) We do not have an answer for this question because there is no scriptual discussion as to how spiritual children are "born."  We know that those who have lived worthy of the Celestial Kingdom will have the privilege of procreation, but we know nothing (and I mean this, NOTHING) about how that happens.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that Mormons expect to have bodies of flesh and bones in heaven?

Yes. Mormons believe that the [resurrection](https://www.lds.org/topics/resurrection?lang=eng) is for everyone

> Through the Atonement of Jesus Christ, all people will be resurrected and saved from physical death (see 1 Corinthians 15:22). Resurrection is the reuniting of the spirit with the body in an immortal state, no longer subject to disease or death.

---

> Or, assuming that God is in the third heaven, is it only those who gain access to 3rd heaven who end up with bodies of flesh and bones?

From the same link as above:

> Although all people will be resurrected, only those who have come unto Christ and partaken of the fulness of His gospel will inherit exaltation in the celestial kingdom.

---

> Will anyone end up in heaven as a spirit person?

No

> Is the physical body the reason for the expectation to be able to procreate in heaven?

I don't know exactly what you mean when you say procreate in heaven but the process by which we, spirit children, of our Heavenly Father are created is not doctrine (the process, not the we being children of God). Not too much is known about what we can do in heaven. However from the [Gospel Fundamentals](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-fundamentals/chapter-36-eternal-life?lang=eng) manual we know:

> To be able to live in this part of the celestial kingdom, people must have been married in the temple and must have kept the sacred promises they made in the temple. They will receive everything our Father in Heaven has and will become like Him. They will even be able to have spirit children and make new worlds for them to live on, and do all the things our Father in Heaven has done.

But how this is done is not described and does not go into further detail.

See also:

[Kingdoms of Glory](https://www.lds.org/topics/kingdoms-of-glory?lang=eng)

[Life After Death](https://www.lds.org/manual/gospel-fundamentals/chapter-35-life-after-death?lang=eng)