# On the body of Satan and Holy Ghost and angels according to Mormons

Tags: lds, heaven, afterlife

This is kind of a follow-up question to my [other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57538/mormon-understanding-of-what-kind-of-bodies-people-have-in-heaven) about the kind of bodies people will have in heaven, according to Mormons.

From the answers it seems that nobody in heaven has a spirit body.

The questions I would like to ask:

1. Do Mormons believe that Satan also has only a physical body?
2. Is there a doctrinal explanation as to why the person "Holy Ghost"
   does not have a body?
3. According to Mormons, if no one in heaven has a physical body, where
   does the concept of spirit beings communicating information between
   God and humans originate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) We believe that Satan does not have and will never have a physical body.  Isa. 14:12:

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning! how
>   art thou cut down to the ground, which didst weaken the nations!

And then, D&C 76:25-27:

> And this we saw also, and bear record, that an angel of God who was in
>   authority in the presence of God, who rebelled against the Only
>   Begotten Son whom the Father loved and who was in the bosom of the
>   Father, was thrust down from the presence of God and the Son, and was
>   called Perdition, for the heavens wept over him—he was Lucifer, a son
>   of the morning.  And we beheld, and lo, he is fallen! is fallen, even
>   a son of the morning!

And finally, D&C 29:36-38:

> And it came to pass that Adam, being tempted of the devil—for, behold,
>   the devil was before Adam, for he rebelled against me, saying, Give me
>   thine honor, which is my power; and also a third part of the hosts of
>   heaven turned he away from me because of their agency; and they were
>   thrust down, and thus came the devil and his angels; and, behold,
>   there is a place prepared for them from the beginning, which place is
>   hell.

We discussed hell and Perdition answering your [last set of questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/57538/mormon-understanding-of-what-kind-of-bodies-people-have-in-heaven/57541#57541).

The LDS Church believes that all people existed spiritually before the Earth was created.  During that "premortal existence" a council in heaven was held where our Heavenly Father presented his plan for our progression.  (We believe [Job 38:4-7](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/ot/job/38.4-7?lang=eng#p3) also refers to this council.)  Lucifer's rebellion against our Father's plan sparked the War in Heaven referred to in [Rev. 12:7-11](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rev/12.7-11?lang=eng#p6).  Having been cast out, he and his followers (a third of the host of heaven) are denied entrance to the Earth and participation in our Father's plan.  Therefore, Lucifer and his followers will not receive bodies.

2) D&C 130:22 teaches the following:

> The Father has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man’s; the Son
>   also; but the Holy Ghost has not a body of flesh and bones, but is a
>   personage of Spirit. Were it not so, the Holy Ghost could not dwell in
>   us.

We know very little about the person we refer to as the Holy Ghost.  Being a part of this Plan, as Christ is, Church dogma (vs. doctrine) suggests that He will eventually have the privilege of a mortal body, resurrection, and exaltation.  However, even saying that is simply speculative.  There is simply no scripture or prophetic commentary that I'm aware of on the matter.

3) Remember that "heaven" is a bit more complicated in the LDS faith.  As for where the idea originates, or where the spirits come from, let's start with one verse, D&C 107:20 states:

> The power and authority of the lesser, or Aaronic Priesthood, is to
>   hold the keys of the ministering of angels, and to administer in
>   outward ordinances, the letter of the gospel, the baptism of
>   repentance for the remission of sins, agreeable to the covenants and
>   commandments.

As for where these ministering spirits come from, consider this: before the Earth was created, and speaking only within the realm of this Earth and not on behalf of any other creation of our Heavenly Father (about which we know practically nothing), those of His children destined for this world were all spirits.  Lucifer fell with a third the host, leaving 2/3 of the host destined for this world who would actually come to it (having "kept their first estate," [Jude 1:6](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/jude/1.6?lang=eng#p5) and [Abraham 3:26-28](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/pgp/abr/3.26-28?lang=eng#p25)).  From the creation of Adam until (perhaps just before) the end of the world there will be spirit children of our Father waiting their turn to recieve mortality on this earth.  Excluding Lucifer and his followers (and describing this very simply... there's a lengthy discussion here), people will be receiving resurrection beginning with Jesus and ending with Judgement.  Therefore, spirits (call them angles if you like) are available to do the Father's and the Son's bidding until the very end.

Comment: One thing to note is that in John 16:13 we learn that "he shall not speak of himself". Most of what we know about the Holy Ghost is via our and interactions with Him. We don't even know His name!